# ComboBox with Checkboxes on selective ComboBox Items

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a `ComboBox` which takes it's values from `ObservableCollection` which gets it's data from a `XML` file.
I am able to display the data from XML to the ComboBox whose code is :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" ItemSource="{Binding Path = <Property Name>}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Now I want to make modifications such that only some `Items` in the `ComboBox` have a checkbox which will be based on the text of the `ComboBox Item`.
If I use `Data Template` in `ComboBox.ItemTemplate`, then all the items of combobox will have the checkbox which I don't want.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ItemTemplate, use the DataTemplate in which there will be triggers that change the Visibility of the flag according to the conditions you need.